# Concept of User Controls in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a screen in my `LibGDX` game that will be essentially two columns, the first being 75% of the real estate and containing labels/buttons, and the next being 25% that will contain text and images.  It is pretty complicated to include all of the code directly in the screen itself for this.

What I would like to do is to have one object contain the logic for the left side of the screen, and one for the right.  This would be similar to `ASP.NET`, where I have a page, with one user control for the left content, and one for the right.

How can this be setup in a `LibGDX` screen?

Comment: While drinor's solution might be correct (it really depends on your needs), it is difficult to determine what exactly you are trying to achieve at the end. Typically, you won't have much code in your screen class, you would delegate most of your logic to other classes and usually the screen would be a starting point for building up your object graph. What you are asking is entirely possible, sounds like standard object orientated programming, but there are infinitely many ways to do it.

Comment: As i said an Inputprocessorclass would be good to to delegate this away from the screenclass. http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [scene2D](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d) and create new class for each element.

For example, you can create one class that extends [Group](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html) for each side. Then you can add a ClickListener to group or to each Actor of the group with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are alot of ways you could do this. You can handle the events yourself by checking the if something is touched and if so, you do handle it yourself by the position.

On the other side you can use the scene2D system by creating `Actors` inside of a Stage and set the `inputprocessor` to the stage. In that case every event is given to the `actors` and if its inside of his bounds he does handle it depending on the implemented way (Take a look at this: [ActionListenes](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d#InputListener)).

1. So in your case you could create 2 `Actors` which are invisible
   and everyone of it has its side.
2. You could also use the `Button`
   from libgdx and use this without a background/foreground or such. Simply set the right sizes and make it invisible by the alpha or no background.
3. or you do check in every cycle of the gameloop if something is touched and if so you do handle the event as you whish. Take a look at this: [input polling](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputPolling) and [creating an input processor](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent)